# How to pivot table unusual table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following data and need to create a pivot table from it. 
I need to see the name of the employee, hr/HD, hourly rate, the date, and if it's AM/PM.

The data starts the first of January, and ends the 31st of December.

[image: Excel data]

I'm struggling to get the data in the correct format to create a pivot table...

Comment: It looks like you already have the data pivoted on date and am/pm. Are you wanting it displayed differently in a pivot table?

Comment: I would merge the Date + AM/PM  so "tue 1-1-10 AM" and "tue 1-1-10 PM" had a column header each. From here just add the datafields in the fieldslist and filter out blanks and off to get the AM/PM. Alternatively create some calculated fields to make it more sexy

Comment: *and need to create a pivot table from it* why? what are you trying to get? *I'm struggling to get the data in the correct format to create a pivot table* Best way to organize your data to become a source for a Pivot Table is using a tabular model, that means. each column should be a field, and first row should be headers. Think that Excel got around 16.000 columns but more than 1 million rows, so it has been clearly designed to work downwards.